# Magento 2.2.1 Changing the store Currency hides the product

Tags: magento2

Can someone help me with Magento 2 Currency switcher issue in Magento 2.2.1?
I've setup the different currencies in my store.when I set the currency Rates field for any currency more than 5 and Change the currency while in the Category page then all the products inside that category are removed,the 'list.phtml' file is also not called.
and if I open the product and then change the currency then the Rates are disappeared for that product but when I'm able to add that product in the cart and price is showing in the cart page.

Comment: try into default setup it might be due to you have any customization code, it should work into default magento2

Comment: @Hit's Yes, it's working with new setup but when in my store it's not working on custom theme as well as default Luma theme. Can you please help me with this issue like what might be the causes?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble.

I've checked the log files and found out that there were changes in the core files due to which the prices for some currencies are not fetched.
So, I've replaced the changed core files with the default files and it's working fine now.